# Which class of probability distributions does the roll of a weighted dice belong to?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Suppose we have a dice that is weighted, and we know how it is weighted.

For example: $P(1)=P(2)=1/12, P(3) =1/3 P(4)=P(5)=P(6)=1/6$

What class of probability distributions is this a part of (or is there none?)

I thought it would be a categorical distribution, with the sides of the dice as categories, but In an answer to a different question I was told that the mean of a categorical random variable doesn't make sense, so now I am unsure if a categorical distribution is the correct choice

(Aside: If the dice was fair then the uniform distribution would be the probability distribution)

Comment: The only category which comes into my mind is that the distribution is discrete.

Comment: Other categories are univariate and asymmetric.

Comment: @callculus so it is not a not a distribution with a name (uniform, normal, binomial, bernoulli, etc)? If so, alright. I just expected it to have a name.

Comment: No, this distribution does not have a specific name, afaik. // Obviously it cannot be normal since it is discrete and asymmetric. And it cannot be uniform since the distribution asymmetric. With the help of the categories you can exclude some distributions from the start.

Comment: @fGDu94 What is your reasoning for your comment? Btw, the random variable is not multinomial distributed.